# Javascript abstractions / passing elements

Tags: javascript

I've created some working code which functions fine :

```
$('#clipboard-copy-button-trackinglink').data('stZclip', new ZeroClipboard($('#clipboard-copy-button-trackinglink')));
```

However, I want to create an abstraction from this :

```
$('#clipboard-copy-button-trackinglink').stZclip($('#clipboard-copy-button-trackinglink'));
```

The abstraction  :

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({ 

        //pass the options variable to the function
        stZclip: function(options) {

           console.log('loading zclip' + options);

           return this.each(function() {
               console.log(this);
               $(this).data('stZclip', new ZeroClipboard(options));
           });
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

My understanding of it was that $('#clipboard-copy-button-trackinglink') would create and pass through a jquery object of the element, and that should then get passed through in the options variable in the abstraction without doing any further transformations. However, I cant see why the first call straight to the zclip method works but the second doesnt ( I know I've called them 2 different ways but have tested both using data() too and no joy)

Comment: ZeroClipboard is not a jQuery plugin, is it?

Comment: What is `ZeroClipboard`? Why is is both available as a constructor and as a jQuery method? Please use the same way to call them (if both don't work) to emphasize your actual problem.

Comment: Thank you. So what does not work now?

Comment: All fixed, yours and sroes comments pushed me back onto the right tracks. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following would give you the same result:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({ 

        //pass the options variable to the function
        stZclip: function(options) {

           console.log('loading zclip' + options);

           return this.each(function() {
               console.log(this);
               $(this).data('stZclip', new ZeroClipboard(options));
           });
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

You are trying to call `ZeroClipboard` as a jQuery plugin, although based on your first example, it seems to be a constructor.

Comment: Just updated my original code to use a constructor. I had been playing around with it for a while

Comment: This was it... I hadnt pushed some changes live for testing. Thanks sroes & Bergi for the sanity check!